# Xpath: How to extract values from URL in Google spreadsheet using importXML function?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I have a xml file that contains the following pattern -

```
<link>
    <clickurl>
        http://www.example.com/fs-bin/click?id=cB97tCVRmeI&offerid=294536.14&type=3&subid=0
    </clickurl>
</link>
```

From the above, I want to store the 'offerid' value (= 294536.14) from `<clickurl>` in a Google spreadsheet.

Comment: Sure this is your XML? It is not well formed, all `&` should be `&amp;` entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs only supports XPath 1.0 in which you cannot apply functions to every single value, but only to aggregated strings. For this reason, you've got to extract the value using Google Docs techniques, XPath won't help here any more.

Use `=ImportXML("http://example.org/your.xml", "//clickurl")` to fetch the data into a helper column. You can hide it if you don't need it. In the next row, use a simple regular expression to extract the variable value: `=regexextract(A1; "[?&]offerid=([^&]*)")`.

I guess there will be a way to do this without a helper column, but I don't know Google Docs well enough for finding one.